# WEKA- ReliefF algorithm

Tags: data-mining, weka, feature-selection

I would like to ask if the ReliefF algorithm for attribute selection,
as implemented in Weka toolkit, performs any normalization in the 
attributes before ranking them.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, internally ReliefF algorithm does min-max normalisation for numeric attributes. You can check the source code of [weka.attributeSelection.ReliefFAttributeEval](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-dev/3.7.5/weka/attributeSelection/ReliefFAttributeEval.java) class to confirm the same.

Comment: Thank you! I also found this paper: http://lkm.fri.uni-lj.si/rmarko/papers/robnik03-mlj.pdf   that proves the fact that ReliefF performs normalization.

Comment: P.S. checking the source code is always a good idea. There might also be programming errors in the classes, so you may want to double-check the code - it might do something different than the original paper. So I wouldn't call this a "proof" of anything. Consider Wekas ReliefF one "interpretation" of the article.